# SQL query to update top 1 record in table

Tags: sql

Can anybody please tell me how to write query to update top 1 record in table ?

Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Could you spare some details? Column information? sample data?

Comment: Depending on the DBMS you use, there may be no guarantee that select top 1 from table always returns the same record even if the data did not change. You may need to find a better criterion than 'top 1'.

Answer (score 12):

YOU have to decide what the top record is in a table, by ordering against a column you decide on.

That said, you could do this in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE [YourTable]
SET [YourColumn] = SomeValue
WHERE [PrimaryKey] IN 
(
   SELECT TOP 1 [PrimaryKey]
   FROM [YourTable]
   ORDER BY [PrimaryKey]  -- You need to decide what column you want to sort on
)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no "top 1 record" in a relational table. Records are not in any order unless you specify one in the query.

Answer (score 2):

in SQLServer you can use the TOP keyword in your update expression:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

When a TOP (n) clause is used with UPDATE, the update operation is performed on a random selection of 'n' number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL, in addition to the existing answers, it is possible to UPDATE the TOP N rows returned through a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql). You are able to define an `ORDER BY` if required, as well.

One advantage of this is that it will work even if your table doesn't have a primary key:

```
WITH Top1Foo AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM Foos
    ORDER BY Name DESC
)
UPDATE Top1Foo
  SET Name = 'zzz';
```

There's a [Example SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf4fa/2)

However, the caveat mentioned by other users remains - using `TOP` implies there are more records meeting the selection criteria, and it risks updating an arbitrary record / records.