# How to execute an UPDATE only if one row would be affected?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server that has a PK (`ID`) and another (logical) primary key made by a couple of other columns (although there is no UNIQUE constraint on that). Let's say, table `PERSON`, `PK = PERSON_ID`, then `NAME`, `SURNAME`, `AGE`

I'd like it was possible to say

```
UPDATE PERSON SET AGE = 43 WHERE NAME = 'XX' AND SURNAME = 'YYY'
```

and have it executed only if 'updated rows' = 1, otherwise (more than 1 row) NO EXECUTION at all. The problem is that I'm not sure if NAME and SURNAME uniquely identify a record, and I have no way to tell it a priori.

Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL update top1 row query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860975/sql-update-top1-row-query) and [Update a single row with t-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909118/update-a-single-row-with-t-sql) and [SQL query to update top 1 record in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855528/sql-query-to-update-top-1-record-in-table)

Comment: @njk -- not a duplicate;  in this case, the user only wants to execute if one row would be updated, and not simply to update the first record.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables My apologies.

Answer (score 8):

Try the below query... it will help you

```
UPDATE PERSON 
SET AGE = 43 
WHERE NAME = 'XX' 
  AND SURNAME = 'YYY' 
  AND 1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PERSON WHERE NAME = 'XX' AND SURNAME = 'YYY)
```

Comment: I've chosen this one because it was the shortest one :). Thx to all.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than writing a complex WHERE clause or IF statement, I usually just wrap the whole thing in a transaction and check @@ROWCOUNT:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE PERSON SET AGE = 43 WHERE NAME = 'XX' AND SURNAME = 'YYY'
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 1 ROLLBACK TRAN ELSE COMMIT TRAN
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd put the conditional before the update rather than in the where clause.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PERSON WHERE NAME = 'XX' AND SURNAME = 'YYY') = 1
UPDATE PERSON SET AGE = 43 WHERE NAME = 'XX' AND SURNAME = 'YYY'
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

something like that should do it.

```
UPDATE Person p1
SET p1.AGE = 43
WHERE NAME = 'XX' AND SURNAME = 'YY'
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL FROM Person p2
  WHERE p1.NAME = p2.NAME
  AND p1.SURNAME = p2.SURNAME
  GROUP BY p2.NAME, p2.SURNAME
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Person p1
SET p1.AGE = 43
WHERE NAME = 'XX' AND SURNAME = 'YY'
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL FROM Person p2
  WHERE p1.NAME = p2.NAME
  AND p1.SURNAME = p2.SURNAME
  AND p1.ID <> p2.ID)
```