# Skip the update query if it affects more than one row

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to execute an UPDATE only if one row would be affected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650197/how-to-execute-an-update-only-if-one-row-would-be-affected)

I have an update query in SQL Server 2005

```
update custom_graphics_files 
set actual_file_Name = @CorrectName 
where actual_file_Name = @FileName
```

Now if there are more than one `actual_file_name`, I want to skip the update query,

Answer (score 1):

```
update t
set t.actual_file_Name = @CorrectName 
FROM custom_graphics_files t
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT actual_file_Name, COUNT(*) TheCount
   FROM custom_graphics_files 
   GROUP BY actual_file_Name
) t2 ON t.actual_file_Name = t2.actual_file_Name AND TheCount = 1
where t.actual_file_Name = @FileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using window functions for this purpose:

```
with toupdate as (
      select cgf.*, COUNT(*) over (PARTITION by actual_file_name) as ActCnt
      from custom_graphics_files
     )
update toupdate
    set actual_file_Name = @CorrectName 
    where actual_file_Name = @FileName and ActCnt = 1
```

On a large table, this may not be the most efficient solution, depending on the selectivity of `actual_file_Name = @FileName`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most "readable" query you can get :

```
update custom_graphics_files 
set actual_file_Name = @CorrectName 
where actual_file_Name = @FileName
and (select count(1) from custom_graphics_files where actual_file_Name = @FileName) = 1
```